# Conditional expressions in sagemath, when defining a symbolic expression

Tags: python, sage

In SageMath, (version 4.7), I do this in the notebook:

```py
var("x y")
dens(x, y) = 2 if y <= x else 0
```

and this gives no error. However, after that,

- `dens(1, 1)` returns `0`,
- `dens(1, 0.5)` returns `0`,
- and so on!

In fact, I found no way to get the answer `2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the Sage function declaration syntax -- f(x,y) = something-or-other -- but on the right hand side you're not putting a Sage expression but a Python one.  This is evaluated when it's declared.  By which I mean:

```
sage: var("x y")
(x, y)
sage: bool(y <= x)
False
sage: dens = 2 if y <= x else 0
sage: dens
0
sage: dens(x,y) = 2 if y <= x else 0
sage: dens
(x, y) |--> 0
```

If you only care about the values that the function take (say, you're plotting it), you can simply use a Python function.  If you want to differentiate it etc. you're in for a harder go of it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

`piecewise` functions are often helpful:
https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/piecewise.html

Also note the slightly different `from sympy import Piecewise` which can handle symbolic conditions.

Still, I'd think that sympy (part of sage) would have symbolic "if" expressions - but can't find anything when googling for "sympy symbolic if".